# redirect to my login page when accessing private subdomains directly through url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, .htaccess

We have created a few authenticated subdomains and further to access it, when a user types in the URL the browser asks for their username and password (using the browser's native login prompt). After the user enters his/her credentials they are directed to the subdomain.

What we require is that if the user tries to access the subdomain directly through the URL, the browser should not prompt for login (which is what is currently happening) but instead should be redirected to my login page. From there, when the user enters their username & password, they will be redirected to the subdomains.

I am using simple web technologies like HTML, Javascript, jQuery and PHP.

Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Without login  it don't allow to access  subdomain .Only Allow after login.Its your requirement right.You can achieve with use of `php session`

Comment: No. Whenever a user enters the URL(http://subdomain.maindomain.io) the browser prompts for Username & Password, I do not want that. What should happen is, when user enters the url(http://subdomain.maindomain.io) it should Not prompt for user credentials but should be directed to my login page(../login.html). Is it possible to redirect to my login page? I do not want the user to access the subdomains directly through url but only via my login page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.href` in javascript to redirected. exemple:

```
location.href = 'login.php'
```

Comment: Yes but the issue is after user have entered the URL (http://subdomain.maindomain.io) in the browser, how and where can i detect that and redirect to my login page?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<?php
    if(!session){
        header('Location: http://subdomain.maindomain.io/login');
        exit;
    }
    else{
       /* some code */
    }
?>
```

S: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

You need to sett a session in php when logged inn, and check that session on subdomain.maindomain.io . I would not use javascript for this (node maby, I am no node expert).